# How to get WEKA Classification Path of ADTree

Tags: java, weka, decision-tree

I'm using WEKA for their implementation of trees for its decision trees. (I am currently using the GUI to test how the program works, but this question is oriented both towards how to do it in GUI or via Java API)

I have put the training data and have learned the model. I also have a sample test which I am running. While the predictions are very accurate, I can't seem to find a way to print the path which the test has gone through. I am interested in knowing which are the variables that have caused the tree to come to that conclusion.

If this is not possible, could someone recommend me a good library with decision trees (adtrees also do the trick) which will return the path for every classified test sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `J48` (C4.5 decision tree) in Weka. It outputs the generated tree with correct and incorrect instance count for each node.

Comment: You can use the generated tree to get the path for each test data manually.

Comment: The thing is that I am most probably going to have a tree that is going to change very often. Thus I would not only be "reeducating" the tree, but I would also have to perform parsing and extraction of the tree's data, which is then going to be applied to new test data. This is cumbersome. Are you sure that there is no way to get the path in Weka? If that's possible via the Java API, it would be great.

Comment: You can get the trained classifier as a if else Java Class with `toSource` method. Check http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Sourcable.html. But you need to alter this class to get the path along.

Comment: I know that I can do that, but I am looking to build an automated system, I can't go through the source code every time and alter the system. Also, since I want to build an automated system, if I did automate the pulling of the source code of the if-else tree, then I would still have to recompile the whole thing if it is to work...

Comment: Rather than using tree you can use rules. For example PART. This outputs the generated rules. You can easily parse these rules.

Comment: So there's definitely no way to display the path through which a test sample has gone, whether it is a rule, tree, or whatever alg, in WEKA? That's very disappointing. I would prefer using the API classifier, instead of performing parsing of the tree/rules and then doing the classification by myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79780/discussion-between-mackiavelli-and-hkn).